# Javascript pattern for handling finished promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I run into this every now and then:

```
return somethingThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then((response) => {
    soSomethingg(); // Eg; update the UI
    return response;
   });
```

Now I'm looking for something that is not expected to return anything and won't change the promise chain if I forget that:

```
return somethingThatReturnsAPromise()
  .whatImLookingFor((response) => {
    doSomething(); // Eg; update the UI
   })
   .then((response) => {
     // and this one should still be able to access response
   });
```

Maybe this goes against the idea of promises, but for me, it's a bit inconvenient since I can't pass arbitrary functions.

One idea is to compose a function:

```
const sideEffect = (callback) => {
  return (response) => {
    callback(response);
    return response;
  };
};
```

And I could use it as

```
return somethingThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(sideEffect(doSomething));
```

But I'd prefer something instead of `then` is there something like that?

Note: I'm working with Angular 1.x so I need something like for that.

Comment: That `sideEffect` is a totally fine solution. What don't you like about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you're not really writing `.then().then()`, because you could collapse that into a single `.then`, but that your concern is really about returning the promise and having some external code add another `then` to the chain. In that case do this:

```
let p = somethingThatReturnsAPromise();
p.then(() => doSomething());
return p;
```

This allows the caller to attach additional `then`s to the original promise instead of chaining off of your `.then`, thereby receiving the original promise's value. This is called *branching* the promise chain.

Comment: I endorse this answer.

Comment: The only drawback is that I have no control over the order of execution but that is fine in most cases.

Comment: @fodma1 If the following promise isn't really dependent on the previous promise's return value or success, you also shouldn't make it dependent on its timing.

Comment: That is true, but wanted to leave it here of someone looks for the same pattern but is confused by this effect.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe this goes against the idea of promises

Slightly, promise chains are pipelines where `then` handlers transform things at each stage. But it's perfectly valid to want to pass through the value unchanged.

> One idea is to compose a function:

Indeed the first thing that came to mind, and how I'd do it.

> But I'd prefer something instead of `then` is there something like that?

There isn't. You could add it for your own projects (I wouldn't in a library) by adding it to `Promise.prototype`. Or you could give yourselve a `Promise` subclass and add it there.

With a Promise sublass you'd do something like:

```
return MyPromise.resolve(somethingThatReturnsAPromise())
  .thenSide(soSomethingg); // Eg; update the UI
```

...where `thenSide` is your method that's `then` but passing the original value back unchanged, e.g.:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    thenSide(callback) {
        this.then(callback);
        return this;
    }
}
```

or

```
class MyPromise extends Promise {
    thenSide(callback) {
        this.then(callback);
        return MyPromise.resolve(this);
    }
}
```

...depending on whether you're bothered about `thenSide` returning the same promise (since `then` always returns a new one).

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, but @deceze's answer is the shortest and cleanest solution for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (I could well be wrong) the wrapper method for "pass-through" side-effects is an idiomatic way to do what you want.

Alternatively (if you need the same `response` in multiple places) you can break up the promise chain when you encounter a situation like this.